# How can I convert db query result to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

original I thought the $query is array object, since I can print these data to a list table like this.
my controller code

```
$data['dates'] = $this->calendar_model->get_cal_eventDate();
$this->load->library('table');
$this->load->view('my_test', $data);
```

my view code

```
echo $this->table->generate($dates);
```

but when I changed my code to try to print $tbDataArr  via `foreach`. It didn't work. How can I convert the $query result (eventDate field values) to array object.

```
function get_cal_eventDate() {
    $this->db->select('eventDate');
        $query = $this->db->get('tb_event_calendar');
        return $query;
}

$tbDataArr = $this->calendar_model->get_cal_eventDate();

foreach ($tbDataArr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($tbDataArr)` - what is your output ?

Comment: What is the current format of result returned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using CodeIgniter? If you are you can do this

```
function get_cal_eventDate() {
    $this->db->select('eventDate');
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_event_calendar');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

If not need more info about what your doing with your PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Codeigniter, right?

Use the `$query->result_array()` method.

see more here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Convert $query->result_array() to $query->result() after add new field in array

    $result = $query->result_array();
    for($i=0;$i<$query->num_rows();$i++){
        //insert new field in array (test_field with value 1)
        $result[$i]+=array('test_field'=>1);
        $result[$i] = (object)$result[$i];
    }
    return $result; //equivalent to return $query->result() without new field;
```